# Array filter with props doesn't seem to work correctly

Tags: vuejs2

According to [the document](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Replacing-an-Array), using `filter` should be very OK. But mine does't work: (try click `Remove One`, and then `Filter One`, and then back on `Remove One`, and then as you can see `Remove` works, but `Filter` does't)

```js
new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
      answers: ['a', 'b', 'c']
    }
  },
  methods: {
    removeOne() {
      this.answers.shift();
      // console.log(this.answers);
    },
    filterOne() {
      this.answers = this.answers.filter((e) => { return e === 'b'});
      console.log(this.answers);
    }
  },
  components: {
    'mytest': {
      template: `<ul><li v-for="(v, i) in myAnswers" :key="i">{{ v }}</li></ul>`,
      props: ['answers'],
      data() {
        return {
          myAnswers: this.answers
        }
      }
    }
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/vue/2.5.17/vue.js"></script>

<div id='app'>
  <mytest :answers="answers"></mytest>
  <input @click="removeOne" type="button" value="Remove One" />
  <input @click="filterOne" type="button" value="Filter One" />
</div>
```

Comment: i think your can use Computed , The problem should be that you filter new this.amswers  Make vue create a new observer , so your view is not update

Comment: @Mars.Tsai Don't know how to use computed in this case. `computed: {
    answers() {
      return ['a', 'b', 'c'];
    }
  },` seems look the same.

Comment: i try use watch is working  https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ropjKy

Comment: you can see https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html   Array Change Detection

Comment: or you can use ref call child component methods , like https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZVveOa

Comment: `ref` seems Good though. Thank you, @Mars.Tsai . But I'm actually confused by all of them ;) I mean when used with `props`, and also with `modifiers, like .sync`...

Comment: `Watch` seems better. I misunderstand `ref`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem is the following:

- You have two components (#app and mytest)
- `answers` is an array in #app data
- You pass a reference to the #app `answers` array to the `mytest` component as a prop.
- in `removeOne` you are mutating the parent `answers` array. It is the same array that `mytest` sees and therefore the `mytest` view updates itself to reflect this change
- in `filterOne` you don't mutate the original array. You replace the parent `answers` array with another one with some elements filtered out. However the `mytest` component still has a reference to the original `answers` array that was passed as a prop that has not been modified by anyone, and therefore the view doesn't change.